# Heap grows for every image loading

Tags: java, android, performance, memory, garbage-collection

In my project I have the simplest listview and adapter with image loading using Picasso. Every decoded image is about 140-150 kbytes..
But during first 30-60 seconds(while Picasso memory LruCache filling) scrolling is laggy.

Here is part of logcat:

```
09-19 14:11:01.435    4676-5700/com.test D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 270K, 11% free 34374K/38228K, paused 60ms, total 61ms
09-19 14:11:01.435    4676-5700/com.test I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 34.487MB for 148408-byte allocation
09-19 14:11:01.505    4676-4676/com.test D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9K, 11% free 34510K/38376K, paused 66ms, total 66ms
09-19 14:11:06.875    4676-5701/com.test D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 132K, 11% free 34497K/38376K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
09-19 14:11:06.875    4676-5701/com.test I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 34.606MB for 147760-byte allocation
09-19 14:11:06.915    4676-4676/com.test D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 34641K/38524K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
09-19 14:11:11.375    4676-5702/com.test D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 110K, 11% free 34650K/38524K, paused 58ms, total 59ms
09-19 14:11:11.385    4676-5702/com.test I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 34.757MB for 149704-byte allocation
09-19 14:11:11.445    4676-4676/com.test D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 34796K/38672K, paused 64ms, total 64ms
09-19 14:11:14.615    4676-5699/com.test D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 119K, 11% free 34796K/38672K, paused 53ms, total 53ms
09-19 14:11:14.625    4676-5699/com.test I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 34.900MB for 149704-byte allocation
09-19 14:11:14.655    4676-4676/com.test D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 34942K/38820K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
```

What I see here:

Heap grows for very image downloading and decoding.

Before heap grows Dalvik try GC some memory.

There’s about 3 Mbytes free of current live heap size according every GL_FOR_ALLOC.

For every next image in listview we need about 300-500kbytes of memory = downloaded bytes(about 60-100kb) + bitmap(140kb) + network staff + views staff.
I confirmed it using memory allocating tracking in Android Studio.

So before heap grows some memory and object without references were collected(freed 270K, freed 119K,...),  and it seems only Bitmap remains.

So my questions:

Why Android cannot allocate 140 or even 500 kbytes even if there is about 3000 kbytes free of current live heap?

Can it be issue of specific device or Android version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every decoded image is about 140-150 kbytes

That is rather large for a `ListView` row, as that is equivalent to about a 390x390 square image.

> Why Android cannot allocate 140 or even 500 kbytes even if there is about 3000 kbytes free of current live heap?

Because "3000 kbytes free of current live heap" is a largely meaningless concept in Android. You are going through `GC_FOR_ALLOC` because there is no single block of free memory big enough for your request.

Quoting [myself](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/16/art-garbage-collection.html), with light edits for readability:

> In Java, on the JVM, if there is no single block of memory big enough, that means that we
>   are actually out of memory (with respect to this request, anyway).
>
> However, the JVM has one thing that the Dalvik VM does not: a compacting garbage collector.
>
> When we write programs in a language running on a runtime supporting garbage collection,
>   we create a bunch of objects, and we later release some subset of those objects. The other
>   ones we hold onto for a while, because we are still using them. In Android, for example,
>   our `Application`, our `ContentProvider`s, our `Thread`s, our own static data members,
>   and so on are going to live for quite some time, in many cases for the duration of the process.
>   Anything they can reach also will not get garbage-collected. So, we allocate a bunch of
>   memory and release some of that memory as our app runs.
>
> With a compacting garbage collector, the long-lived objects get slid around in memory,
>   to allow the freed-up blocks of memory to be coalesced. The net is that all free heap
>   space should be available as one contiguous block, eligible for allocation.
>
> (the details are more complicated than that, but this is a Stack Overflow answer, not a dissertation)
>
> With a non-compacting garbage collector, nothing is slid around in memory. We wind up
>   with heap fragmentation, as what was once a pristine 16MB (or 32MB, or 48MB, or whatever)
>   heap now is a bunch of objects with interspersed free memory. Even though we might
>   have 10MB of free heap space, if the largest single block of that free heap space is only
>   1MB, we cannot allocate an 8MB `Bitmap`, because there is no free block big enough.
>
> The Dalvik VM has a non-compacting garbage collector.

Note that ART (Android 5.0+) has a garbage collector that compacts, but only when the app is in the background.

Comment: Thanks. At first glance it make sense. What's about sizes which heap grows, from the log I see the next size of heap: 38228K, 38376K, 38524K, 38672K. 
Every growing is about only 100-200K. But in my device dalvik.vm.heapminfree = 500K and dalvik.vm.heapmaxfree = 2m. So the heap should grow for 1M in average..i think it should be enough to have free single block for next image. Probably I completely wrong..

Comment: @KirillOlenyov: "So the heap should grow for 1M in average" -- I do not know how you came to that conclusion. I do not know the algorithm used by the GC engine for how much system RAM to allocate to use to expand the heap when a `GC_FOR_ALLOC` condition arrives.

Comment: Ok, never mind) Do you have any suggestions how to investigate memory fragmentation?

Comment: @KirillOlenyov: "Do you have any suggestions how to investigate memory fragmentation?" -- not really. I am not aware of any means of determining what size blocks are available in the heap. Instead, I would focus on using less memory and reusing the memory that you allocate. I did [a presentation on "Top Ten Memory Management and Tuning Tips" at Samsung's 2014 developer conference](https://commonsware.com/videos) with some advice.